# SharePoint Lookup Column Sorting the Referenced List and I don't want it to

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I created a simple cross reference of military ranks to military grades CSV and imported to SharePoint to create a list.

Example

- RANK GRADE
- CPT  O-3
- MAJ  O-4
- etc

In a separate list, I added a column Lookup pointing to the Rank:Grade list so users could select a Rank and the corresponding grade would automatically populate.

Maddengly, the New Item userform insists on sorting the Ranks alphabetically in the drop down menu instead of in the order on the referenced list which is lowest to highest rank.

This was intended to save time and reduce chance of erroneous data entry but has sucked up an hour of my morning trying to figure out. It otherwise works, I just prefer the items display in the order I placed them as it's the proper way to list ranks in a list and appears more professionally done.

Does anyone have a suggestion?  I don't want the drop down menu to sort the referenced list, I just want it to display the order the list is already in.

I tried setting up a "SortOrder" column on the referenced list and enforcing a sort of the list based on that column.  Did not affect the drop down menu in the userform, it still displays ranks alphabetically instead of how they are ordered in the list.